# active_record-acts_as - validate parent fields on child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and the [active_record-acts_as](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) gem.

This gem simulates multi-table inheritance for ActiveRecord models.

I have my parent model called *Attachment* with child models *Specification* and *Release*.

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable
end

class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :attachment
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :attachment
end
```

My *Attachment* model has fields `name`, `actable_id`, `actable_type` (used by acts_as gem) and the standard paperclip fields.

*Specification* and *Release* have multiple fields specific to their type (so I don't think they are good candidates for single table inheritance).

What I am trying to do is validate `name` on the child models instead of the parent, as different rules apply to *Release* and *Specification*.

Presence validations seem to work fine:

```
class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :attachment

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

But when I try something like:

```
class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :attachment

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }
end
```

I get the following error when calling .valid?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for nil:NilClass
```

I wrote some custom validations which work on the child model, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to.

The main reason for validating on the child was because I use the following to get more concise error messages depending on the model (Specification, Release):

```
class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    name: "Version"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end
end
```

So it returns something like:

`Version can't be blank.` instead of `Name can't be blank.`

I also tried validating on *Attachment* (the parent) using something like:

```
with_options if: Proc.new { |x| x.actable_type == "Specification" } do |s|
  s.validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }
end
```

But then I don't get the error messages I want. `Name` instead of `Version`.

I am probably massively over complicating things. Any ideas?

Comment: If you combine the `HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES` on the child class approach plus validating `:name` on the `Attachment` like you have at the end of your question does that give you what you want?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and I would happily settle for this. However, I couldn't work out how to select the right `HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES` hash from the respective child model (Specification, Release). I probably have missed something very obvious.

Comment: I reproduced your situation with active_record-acts_as (1.0.5), rails 4.2 and ruby 2.2 and sqlite -- everything seems to work normally, cant make it fail with similar error. Do you have  `t.integer  "actable_id"` and `t.string   "actable_type"` for the attachments table in your `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: Could you show couple of backtrace lines for the error you get?

Comment: (I thought the error is on [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L66) line, but it won't fail even if i delete column manually from db not touching anything in the app...)

Comment: Hi @EvgenyPetrov. [Here is the full trace at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4Z9tUF8U). I do have the two columns `t.integer "actable_id"` and `t.string "actable_type"`.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that `Attachment` has another column named `folder_id` and `belongs_to :folder`. `Folder` uses the gem `ancestry` to have a tree like structure with itself, a `t.string "name"` and a column `t.string "attachment_type"` which is used just for information. `Folder` `has_many: :attachments`. Maybe this causes issues?

Comment: It seems at some point `klass.columns_hash[attribute_name]` returns nil, some class in the hierarchy doesn't have name column, but rails tries to validate it, I'll dig into later and give it a try with the ancenstry gem, but imho it shouldn't affect validations...

Comment: Still can't get the error, in case you want to try my version I've put it [here](https://app.box.com/s/u2nnygcjaexsfed52ezjzj9yp6skdek8), there are models only (Specification, Attachment, List(=your Folder),Release), so you can try it in the console.

Comment: You have a column called `name` on `Specification`, whereas I don't. If you remove that column and try to validate you will get the same error I suspect (I just did when I used the test you created). I am probably going about it the wrong way, the thing I don't understand is I can validate the presence of `name` on the `Specification` model, but not anything more complex (i.e. uniqueness).

Comment: That's it, you don't have specifications.name in the db. When you validate presence it checks only attribute, when you check uniqueness it seeks in the db for this column. To get attachment name you can use specification.attachment.name.

Comment: And it seems all attachment validations should go to the Attachment model.

Comment: Ah yes, so that is where the `nil:NilClass` comes from in the error. Thanks for working this out with me. I actually have an example in my question of validating on the Attachment model. The issue I currently have with this is the error messages would return something like `Name can't be blank`, but would prefer something like `Version can't be blank.`. I think I almost had it with using a HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES hash on the child class and the class method `human_attribute_name`, but I can't work out how to pass the correct child's hash to this method (if it is even possible).

Comment: You can try to switch them depending on the Attachment.actable_type attribute, right in the Attachment validator.

Comment: I've noticed that it's possible to pass scopes to acts_as, so this should work: `acts_as :attachment, -> {joins :attachments}` it should add the missing name column. Will try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Evgeny Petrov worked out, it isn't possible to validate parent attributes on the child models (probably can be done with a custom Validator).

In the end I opted for validating on the parent model using `with_options if:` to target certain `actable_type`s.

And in order to sort out some custom error messages, I combined the `HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES` hash on the child class with `self.human_attribute_name` on the parent.

Here is an example:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable

  before_validation :set_humanized_attributes

  class << self; attr_reader :humanized_attributes end
  @humanized_attributes = {}

  with_options if: proc { |x| x.actable_type == 'Release' do |s|
    s.validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  end

  with_options if: proc { |x| x.actable_type == 'Specification' do |s|
    s.validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }
  end

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
    humanized_attributes[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

  private

  def set_humanized_attributes
    @humanized_attributes = actable_type.constantize::HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES
  end
end

class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :attachment
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    name: 'Version'
  }

  # child attribute validations here
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :attachment
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    name: 'Release'
  }

  # child attribute validations here
end
```

In rails console:

```
> s = Specification.new
=> #<Specification id ... >
> s.valid?
=> false
> s.errors.full_messages
=> ["Version can't be blank"]
> r = Release.new
=> #<Release id ... >
> r.valid?
=> false
> r.errors.full_messages
=> ["Release can't be blank"]
```

Need to check some edge cases and make it more robust, but for now this is achieving what I required.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize a discussion in the comments above for one that encounter similar error:

---

The problem was in the absence of specifications.name column in the db.

When you validate presence it checks only attribute, when you check uniqueness it seeks in the db for this column.